# redis-cli 'sentinel slaves redis-cluster' returns an empty list with a password protected master

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, redis-cluster, redis-cli

```
sentinel slaves <master>
```

returns an empty list with a password protected master.

---

My current redis-cluster setup is the following:
3 Different linux servers

- srv 1 => redis master + sentinel 1
- srv 2 => redis slaves + sentinel 2
- srv 3 => sentinel 3 (sentinel only to avoid split brain situation)

### the redis version

```
redis_version:3.2.3
redis_mode:sentinel
os:Linux 3.10.0-514.21.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64
tcp_port:26379
```

For some reason sentinel can't find a suitable slave to promote "master" in case of failover.

the redis-cli command:

```
sentinel slaves redis-cluster
```

returns me an empty list :/ (see my terminal output below) BUT the 3 sentinels can "talk" to each other

### the 3 redis-cli sentinel commands I used to get these information:

```
ip-10-0-0-118.eu-west-1.compute.internal:26379> sentinel slaves redis-cluster
(empty list or set)
ip-10-0-0-118.eu-west-1.compute.internal:26379> sentinel ckquorum redis-cluster
OK 3 usable Sentinels. Quorum and failover authorization can be reached
ip-10-0-0-118.eu-west-1.compute.internal:26379> sentinel failover redis-cluster
(error) NOGOODSLAVE No suitable slave to promote
```

The configuration files (redis and sentinel) are basics and I used the authentication.

Any idea what would I have misconfigured? so far? :/

#### documentation:

- https://redis.io/topics/sentinel
- http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/sentinel.conf

#### here are my sentinel logs:

```
. . .
2361:X 17 Jul 09:20:55.159 # 04ffbe62cec24e9635abbf8985c804e27bb8899b voted for 2cd4dce89889baadc178ba8909b894cf42f184d9 23
2361:X 17 Jul 09:20:55.170 # f5e93cc7c1a109ca8aa4588b92156f7fb5c29c72 voted for 2cd4dce89889baadc178ba8909b894cf42f184d9 23
2361:X 17 Jul 09:20:55.221 # +elected-leader master redis-cluster 10.0.0.223 6379
2361:X 17 Jul 09:20:55.221 # +failover-state-select-slave master redis-cluster 10.0.0.223 6379
2361:X 17 Jul 09:20:55.304 # -failover-abort-no-good-slave master redis-cluster 10.0.0.223 6379
2361:X 17 Jul 09:20:55.357 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Mon Jul 17 09:26:55 2017
2361:X 17 Jul 09:21:41.876 # +new-epoch 24
2361:X 17 Jul 09:21:41.878 # +vote-for-leader f5e93cc7c1a109ca8aa4588b92156f7fb5c29c72 24
2361:X 17 Jul 09:21:41.920 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Mon Jul 17 09:27:42 2017
2361:X 17 Jul 09:27:42.092 # +new-epoch 25
2361:X 17 Jul 09:27:42.092 # +try-failover master redis-cluster 10.0.0.223 6379
2361:X 17 Jul 09:27:42.099 # +vote-for-leader 2cd4dce89889baadc178ba8909b894cf42f184d9 25
2361:X 17 Jul 09:27:42.102 # f5e93cc7c1a109ca8aa4588b92156f7fb5c29c72 voted for 2cd4dce89889baadc178ba8909b894cf42f184d9 25
2361:X 17 Jul 09:27:42.103 # 04ffbe62cec24e9635abbf8985c804e27bb8899b voted for 2cd4dce89889baadc178ba8909b894cf42f184d9 25
2361:X 17 Jul 09:27:42.165 # +elected-leader master redis-cluster 10.0.0.223 6379
2361:X 17 Jul 09:27:42.165 # +failover-state-select-slave master redis-cluster 10.0.0.223 6379
2361:X 17 Jul 09:27:42.248 # -failover-abort-no-good-slave master redis-cluster 10.0.0.223 6379
2361:X 17 Jul 09:27:42.314 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Mon Jul 17 09:33:42 2017
. . .
```

If I trust the following forum,

> ... sentinel only promote good slaves to new master. some slaves can be good slave to follow below rules.
>
> - not slave-priority is 0.
> - not demote(it was not old master.)
> - ping reply > info_validity_time
> - info reply > info_validate_time
> - not sdown, odown, disconnected.
>
> *[Source: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1796]*

Comment: related issues: https://github.com/antirez/redis/search?q=failover-abort-no-good-slave&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 1):

My problem was actually a misconfiguration in my redis-cluster files (redis.conf & redis-sentinel.conf)which launched my two redis instances in 'standalone' mod.

I put the working configuration on my github repository: [github.com/orsius/redis-cluster][1]

Hope it'll help someone one day.

Keep calm and continue using redis-cluster;)
Orsius.

[1]: https://github.com/orsius/redis-cluster

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was missing the slaveof x.x.x.x 6379 configuration setting on nodes 2 and 3.